# Plastic SCM Forgot Encryption password

Tags: plasticscm

Hello guys i made a workspace and i dont know when it asked for encrption password. I forgot the password and now my developer cannot pull code, he is always prompted for encryption password.
So what is the solution, should i make a new workspace or make a new Plastic SCM account and then a new workspace.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption configuration is stored in the following paths: You can share the files with your coworker:

**Server-side encryption configuration:**

C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server\cryptedservers.conf

C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server*.key

**Client-side encryption configuration:**

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\plastic4\cryptedservers.conf

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\plastic4*.key

Comment: Hi @carlos, I have :  Client-side encryption configuration:

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\plastic4\cryptedservers.conf.                                                                 Server-side encryption configuration:

C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server*.key                                                               So i am missing some of the files. And which files should i send to my developer.